# HM-10 and Arduino Due

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-due

I am trying to communicate between HM-10 module (without any breadboard or soldering) and experience problem with reading data from serial.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#define TO_HEX(i) (i <= 9 ? '0' + i : 'A' - 10 + i)

void afterSetup() {
  Serial3.write("AT+NAME?");
  delay(500);
}

void setup() {
  // initialize both serial ports:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  /*Serial3.begin(115200);  // The Bluetooth Mate defaults to 115200bps
  delay(100);  // Short delay, wait for the Mate to send back CMD
  Serial3.println("U,9600,N");  // Temporarily Change the baudrate to 9600, no parity
  // 115200 can be too fast at times for NewSoftSerial to relay the data reliably*/
  Serial3.begin(9600);  // Start bluetooth serial at 9600

  Serial.write("\n\n\n==== START ====\n");

  afterSetup();
}

unsigned char mode = 2;

void wr(HardwareSerial*, int);

void wr(HardwareSerial *target, int bt, unsigned char mode) {
    //target->write(TO_HEX(((bt & 0xF000) >> 12 )));
    //target->write(TO_HEX(((bt & 0x0F00) >> 8 )));
    if(mode > 0) {
      target->write("\t\t\t\t");
    }
    target->write(TO_HEX(((bt & 0x00F0) >> 4 )));
    target->write(TO_HEX((bt & 0x000F)));
    target->write(" (");
    target->write(bt);
    target->write(")\n");
    return;
}

void loop() {

  // read from port 1, send to port 0:
  if (Serial3.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial3.read();

    if(mode != 1) {
      mode = 1;
    }

    wr(&Serial, inByte, 1);
  }

  // read from port 0, send to port 1:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial.read();
    Serial3.print((char)inByte);

    if(mode != 0) {
      mode = 0;
    }

    wr(&Serial, inByte, 0);
  }
}
```

Wiring is simple:

```cpp
HM-10    | due
-------------------
RX       | TX3
TX       | RX3
VCC      | 3V3
GND      | GND
```

Basically, I am able to get data from serial, but it **corrupted**.

Here is an example:

- Command: AT+NAME?
- Expected: HMSoft
- Response:

  ```cpp
          28 (()
          25 (%)
          2A (*)
          35 (5)
          15 ()
          FE (�)
  ```

And another, simpler:

- Command:  AT
- Expected: OK
- Response: F5

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you printing from `Serial3` before calling `begin()` on it?